# Modifying values within a list

Tags: c#, list

I've been trying to write a program which can scan a raw data file and normalize it for data mining processes, I've trying to read the data from the file and store it in a list this way:

```
public static List<Normalize> NF()
    {
        //Regex r = new Regex(@"^\d+$");
        List<Normalize> N = new List<Normalize>();
        StreamReader ss = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\NN.txt");
        String Line = null;
        while (!ss.EndOfStream) {
            Line = ss.ReadLine();
            var L = Line.Split(',').ToList();
            N.Add(new Normalize { age = Convert.ToInt16(L[0]), 
                                  Sex = L[1], 
                                  T3 = Convert.ToDouble(L[2]),
                                  TT4 = Convert.ToDouble(L[3]),
                                  TFU = Convert.ToDouble(L[4]),
                                  FTI = Convert.ToDouble(L[5]),
                                  RC = L[6],
                                  R = L[7]
            });
        }
        return N;
    }
}
struct Normalize {
   public int age;
   public String Sex;
   public double T3;
   public double TT4;
   public double TFU;
   public double FTI;
   public String RC;
   public String R;
}
```

At this moment I want to go through the list that I've made and categorize the data , similar to this :

```
   var X= NF();
   for (int i = 0; i < X.Count; i++) {
            if (X[i].age > 0 && X[i].age <= 5) { // Change the X[i].age value to 1 }
            else if (X[i].age > 5 && X[i].age <= 10) { // Change the X[i].age value to 2 }
            ...
        }
```

But the compiler says X[i].[variable name] is not a variable and cannot be modified in this way. My question is, what would be an efficient way to perform this operation.

Comment: Where is `X` defined?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I'll edit my question.

Comment: `struct Normalize` is a value type, not a reference type, therefore you cannot change its fields like that. Change it to `class Normalize`

Comment: Why is `Regex r` declared?

Comment: Yes @Alex is correct. In case you need to mutate a struct, your design is wrong. Consider redesigning your `struct` to `class`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: You are very right, I have to admit I made a very silly mistake.

Comment: @BytesOracle shall I add it as the answer, so you can close the question, or do you prefer deleting the question?

Comment: @Alex Of course alex, I will definitely accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct Normalize` is a value type, not a reference type, therefore you cannot change its fields like that. Change it to `class Normalize`

Answer (score 1):

Change **`struct Normalize`** to **`class Normalize`** and iterate with foreach loop. It's way cleaner.
You could also set variables to private and use getters/setters to check/set variable.

```
foreach (Normalize x in X)
{
    if (x.getAge() > 0 && x.getAge() <= 5)
        x.setAge(1)
    ...
}
```

**Edit:**
just saw you already got your answer

Answer (score 1):

Modifying struct field is fine as long as it's a single entity (Given its a `mutable struct`). This is possible -

```
var obj = new Normalize();
obh.Age = 10;
```

But in your case you are accessing the struct using indexer from the list.

`Indexer will return copy of  your struct and modifying the value won't reflect it back to the list` which ain't you want.

Hence compiler is throwing error to stop you from writing this out.

As [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18432555/632337) mentioned, you should go for creating class instead of struct if you want to modify it.

On a side note, its always advisable to have `immutable structs` instead of mutable structs.